# use Win32::Registry gives problems in Linux machine

Tags: windows, linux, perl, registry

My perl script must run on windows as well as Linux server. As the script runs, I have to update the registry for specific things. When I use "use Win32::Registry" It works fine on windows but on Linux it gives errors regardless of the following if statement.

```
if ($OS =~ /Windows/ )
{
use Win32::Registry;
...
...
}
```

In my view, perl loads "use" at compilation time and that must be the problem. What can I do so that Perl does not load use win 32 command when running on Linux?

I tried using

```
if ($OS =~ /Windows/ )
{
require Win32::Registry;
...
...
}
```

with this, the script runs fine on both servers but it saves binary values in registry and not string value.

So how can I make the Perl script run on both servers and save string values in registry?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use Foo;
```

is

```
BEGIN {
   require Foo;
   import Foo;
}
```

so use

```
BEGIN {
   if ($OS =~ /Windows/)
      require Win32::Registry;
      import Win32::Registry;
   }
}
```

or

```
use if $OS =~ /Windows/, 'Win32::Registry';
```

- [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)
- [`if` pragma](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?if)

Comment: when I use 
BEGIN {
   if ($OS =~ /Windows/)
      require Win32::Registry;
      import Win32::Registry;
   }
}

It takes REG_NONE as type but not REG_SZ even if i specify.